# bitwise NOT of negative integer

Tags: java

I am a little confused with how we find the bitwise NOT of negative integers. For a positive integer 'a'

1. Show the binary form of 'a'
2. Convert all the 0s to 1s and vice versa
3. Label it as '~a'
4. Find the 2's compliment of '~a' and convert that back into integer
5. Attach the sign of '~a' to the integer we got from Step 4 and thus we have our bitwise NOT of 'a'.

Using the same method when I try to find the bitwise NOT of any negative integer I am getting a different answer.

Comment: Negative integer=not of the positive operation plus 1 (2's complement)

Comment: Your code, please? It’s much easier to work with your question if we are getting concrete.

Comment: Is it here a homework for the community?

Comment: @dan1st that is pretty much what I do when I am trying to calculate it in my head but I wanted to know how bitwise NOT actually works.

Comment: It just flips every bit

Comment: So you're saying that this implementation of `~a` only applies to the number of bits needed to display `a` in binary form, i.e. it ignores the bit-length of the variable storing the value (e.g. 32 for `int`)? So other than defining `~0 = 1`, it means to invert all bits up to the left-most 1-bit, so to use `byte` as an example, `~18 = ~0b00010010 = 0b00001101 = 13`, but `~13 = ~0b1101 = ~0b0010 = 2`, so applying `~` twice will not revert to the original value. Wouldn't that mean that for negative numbers, you'd do the same up to leftmost 0-bit? E.g. `~-9 = ~0b11110111 = 0b11111000 = -8`?

Comment: @Andreas No I use all 32-bit for ```int```. For example when ```a = 4``` we see that it works fine.

Comment: I see that my question has a negative upvote. What was wrong with my question? I am new to this site and I don't completely understand how things work here. I want to improve how I ask and answer questions, so I would really like it if you would help me.

Comment: My guess is the downvote is because you don't show the code that gives a different answer to what you expect. It would make it much easier for people to help

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know how bitwise NOT actually works.

It turns a 1 bit to a 0 bit, and a 0 bit to a 1 bit.

So, if I had a 16 bit binary number `1111000011110000`, bitwise NOT of that would be `0000111100001111`.

For more information on Java bitwise operators, read the [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) page of the Oracle Java Tutorial

Comment: Ya that is how I knew it works, but then why is it that when printing it shows a completely different integer.

Comment: @ShayanDasgupta Different from what? Because `4` is a 32-bit value, in hex it is `0x00000004`, so `~4` is `0xfffffffb` in hex, which means `-5` since `int` values are in two's compliment. If you didn't expect `~4` to be `-5`, what did you expect that 32-bit two's compliment number to be? --- And since applying NOT twice get you back to the original number, `~-5 = ~0xfffffffb = 0x00000004 = 4`.

Comment: You need to explain how you are "printing it".  And what "it" is.  Please add the details to the question.